# How to use Bitwise for security groups

Tags: c#, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I'm sure i've done this before, but I can't remember how to do it and I cannot find any help.

If I have the following security access:

```
1: Read
2: Write
4: Delete
8: View
```

A user can have a combination of any of these, say Write and View, so their security number would be 10.

How can I check it against each security group to see if they have access?

I thought it was 2 MOD 10 but this doesn't appear to work.

What is the simplest way to approach this issue? Am I missing a bitwise operation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You [AND](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#AND) with the applicable number and check if it's greater than 0, i.e. 10 & 2 > 0, thus you have write permission.